# Merging JavaScript code into the <head> with sitemesh and jsp's

Tags: java, jsp, sitemesh

I'm using sitemesh to decorate my web pages. Can someone guide me on the best practice. The `header.jsp` and `sidebar.jsp` have JavaScript code dependencies and I would like to merge these into the head along with the main page which is being decorated.

Basically I want to decorate both the HTML and the `<head>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code in healder.jsp is between `<head></head>`, sitemesh will, by default, append it into the `<head></head>` of the main decorator.

Comment: Thanks bluefoot. Do you know of a decent tutorial site for using sitemesh with jsp's?

Comment: well, the official website always was enough for me. but there's a lot of resources if you look on google